# Extract English words from a text in R

Tags: r, text, cpu-word

I have a text and I need to extract all English words from it. For instance I want to have a function which would analyse the vector

```
vector <- c("picture", "carpet", "lamp", "notaword", "anothernotaword")
```

And return only English words from this vector i.e. "picture", "carpet", "lamp"

I do understand that the definition of "English word" depends on the dictionary but I would be satisfied even with a basic dictionary.

Comment: not sure, but you might take a look at the `qdap` package

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it before but I could not install it      Loading required package: qdapTools
Error : object ‘setDT’ is not exported by 'namespace:data.table'
Error: package ‘qdapTools’ could not be loaded

Comment: try updating/re-installing latest versions (start with `data.table`, then `qdap`)

Comment: Thank you, that solved some of the problems. And now I am just stuck with setDT installation: `package ‘setDT’ is not available`. Do you by any chance know any ways to solve that?

Comment: @Kate `setDT` is in the **data.table** package.  Your problem should be solved for installing **qdap**.

Comment: @TylerRinker Thank you for the solution. But I am still confused about this packages. I have installed **qdap** package, but I could not use some function from it. For instance I have tried to use **which_misspelled()** and R replied that there are no such function. If for future I would need to use **qdap** what might fix the problem?

Comment: @Kate can you ask this of site at **qdap**'s issues page?  When you open an issue post the error messages and the results from `sessionInfo()`  Here's the issues page: https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the package I maintain **qdapDictionaries** (no need for the parent package **qdap** to be installed).  If your data is more complex you may need to use tools like `tolower` etc. to make it work.  The idea here is basically to see where a known word list `?GradyAugmented` intersects with your words.  Here are two very similar approaches, the first is likely slightly faster depending on data:

```
vector <- c("picture", "carpet", "lamp", "notaword", "anothernotaword")

library(qdapDictionaries)
vector[vector %in% GradyAugmented]

## [1] "picture" "carpet"  "lamp"

intersect(vector, GradyAugmented)

## [1] "picture" "carpet"  "lamp"
```

The error you are receiving with installing **qdap** sounds like @Ben Bolker is correct.  You will need a newer version (I'd suggest the latest version) of [**data.table**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) installed (use `packageVersion("data.table")` to check this).  That is an oversight on my part with not requiring a minimal version of **data.table**, I thought `setDT` (a function in the **data.table** package) was always around but it appears to not be in your version.  But to solve this particular problem you wouldn't need to install the parent **qdap** package, just **qdapDictionaries**.