# Remove both English and Non-English names from a dataframe

Tags: r, string, replace, text-mining, data-cleaning

I am working with several hundreds of rows of a junk data. A dummy data is as thus:

```
   foo_data <- c("Mary Smith is not here", "Wiremu Karen is not a nice person",
                  "Rawiri Herewini is my name", "Ajibade Smith is my man", NA)
```

I need to remove all names (both English and non-English first names and family names such that my desired output will be:

```
[1] "is not here"         " is not a nice person" " is my name"  
[4] "is my man"           NA
```

However, using textclean package, I was only able to remove English names leaving the non-English names:

```
library(textclean)
textclean::replace_names(foo_data)

[1] "  is not here"     "Wiremu  is not a nice person"    "Rawiri Herewini is my name"  
[4] "Ajibade  is my man"           NA
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Flip it: You want to extract English words. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715380/extract-english-words-from-a-text-in-r

Comment: Hi @Roland, I have followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715380/extract-english-words-from-a-text-in-r  but the result is not what is desired.

Comment: The point was not for you to copy that answer. The point was that you need a dictionary and that answer mentions one.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
s <- textclean::replace_names(foo_data)
trimws(gsub(sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', 
      paste0(unlist(hunspell::hunspell(s)), collapse = '|')), '', s))

[1] "is not here"          "is not a nice person" "is my name"           "is my man"            NA
```

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu. When I ran your code for small dataset, it looks fine but on a large dataset, it shows this error: ```Error in gsub(sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", paste0(unlist(hunspell::hunspell(foo_data)),  : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634```